# Sagemaker notebook vs Sagemaker container

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, machine-learning, jupyter-notebook, amazon-sagemaker

What is the key difference between training, testing and deploying machine learning algorithms in SageMaker's notebooks vs SageMaker's containers?

I do not completely understand the different use cases for both alternatives, when it is appropriate to use one over the other. At a first glance, structuring a whole ML project using Docker containers seem more complex than building the same project on a Jupyter notebook, so the Docker solution is not quite obvious to me.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to choose between using SageMaker Notebook or "SageMaker Containers", these are not alternative services. [SageMaker Notebook](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/nbi.html) is a managed Jupyter Notebook running on EC2 instances where containers are simply the medium for where training/inference actually occurs. SageMaker containers do not exist in the context you are referring.

I believe you may be confusing [Prebuilt SageMaker Images](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/pre-built-containers-frameworks-deep-learning.html) with the [BYOC](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/docker-containers-adapt-your-own.html) functionality. The former is a collection of existing images where the latter allows you to adapt existing Docker images you already created to work in SageMaker.